# Xamarin - @(Content) build action is not supported

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, build, action

My Xamarin application will build but won't deploy, I'm getting a bunch of warnings that say "@(Content) build action is not supported" which other people seem to have fixed by setting the AndroidManifest.xml build action to "None" but my AndroidManifest.xml's build action is already set to none, I've gone through the files the error list is specifying and all of their build actions are set to "Android Resource" rather than "Content". A couple of them were .xml files set to "Content" so I switched them to "None" but the remaining 17 are .png files set to "Android Resource" and I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hi did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin: @(Content) build action is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027774/xamarin-content-build-action-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the **AndroidManifest.xml**, the **Build Action** of the **AssemblyInfo.cs** also needs to be set as None.

The **Build Action** of all the **Layout** files should also be set as **AndroidResource**.

After that, it's always good practice to **clean** your solution then **rebuild** it