# Xamarin: @(Content) build action is not supported

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Android App in VS Pro 2015(Xamarin). Everything worked fine until this morning when I updated my Android device. **I'm able to build my application but while deploying to my device** I get a bunch of warnings that say **`@(Content) build action is not supported`** which other people seem to have fixed by setting the **AndroidManifest.xml** build action to **None** but my **AndroidManifest.xml**'s build action is already set to none.

I have checked all the specified files in the warnings. Most of them are `.png` with Build action set to **Android Resource** (I've also tried with Build Action -> `Content` with no luck) and a couple of them are `.xml` with Build action set to **Content**.

Here is the screenshot of my code window.

[image: Warnings]

For duplicate markers: I have already tried the Xamarin posts related to this on stack exchange. Hardly there should be 20 posts! But none worked out for me.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the `AndroidManifest.xml` and then select "**Properties**".

**In Properties Window -> set "Build Action" as None**

I take [it](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74365/content-build-action-is-not-supported) as reference, hope it helps.

Comment: could you explain more of it?

Answer (score 2):

Open project folder and remove **bin** and **obj** folders, remove application from the device and try one more time.

Comment: I'm unable to deploy to the device dude. Everything else working fine with no errors.

Comment: That strange, warnings do not prevent from deploying on the device, only errors can. Are you sure there are no errors in "Deploy on device" pad?

Comment: Yes. There are no errors. The warnings are shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is android resources you need to get the property of the mentioned file and set:

```
Build Action: AndroidResource
Custom Tool: MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles
```

Then recompile and when you get the warning again, just double click on the warning to open the text file associated with it, Make sure to delete this file from your project. This file will not be generated again. (You can find the file location by hovering your mouse on the file tab title).

Answer (score 0):

I had five pictures for image button, it worked fine.Being lazy, I copied the code to another project for reuse and (all the 5) pictures were not showing and I got the warning 
**@content build action is not supported**
I just thought why other pictures (pictures which I had inserted new as per procedure) are showing up? right clicked them and saw their build action to be **AndroidResource** I changed the BuildAction of my (problematic) button pictures to AndroidResource and voila it is working

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the **AndroidManifest.xml**, the **Build Action** of the **AssemblyInfo.cs** also needs to be set as **None**.

The **Build Action** of all the **Layout** files should also be set as **AndroidResource**.

After that, it's always good practice to **clean** your solution then **rebuild** it

Answer (score 0):

When i got the error. The file mentioned was an XML file. And i found that in the property of that XML file build action was set to content. And i changed it to AndroidResource and it fixed my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted this down.  This is what actually worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for an answer. Paul Chang's answer tipped me off. When I ran a build it told me the `packages.config` was where this warning was originating. I changed the `Build Action` to `None` in the Properties for that file and poof! No more warning.